Rotate gradually by constant from clockwise or counterclockwise direction
I have a rectangle object that may target a set of static $4 + (2 + 2)$ (NORTH, NORTHWEST, NORTHEAST, SOUTH, SOUTHWEST, SOUTHEAST, WEST, SOUTH) different target rotation degrees by applying gradual increments in the current rotation per frame.
I have the criteria that the angles ($\text{current rotation}, \text{target rotation}$) be between $[0, 360)$.
Given $\text{current rotation} = 0$ and $\text{target rotation} = 180$, the current rotation increments gradually by 5 until 180:

Frame 1 = $\text{current rotation} = 5$
Frame 4 = $\text{current rotation} = 20$
Frame (last) = $\text{current rotation} = \text{target rotation} = 180$

Given $\text{current rotation} = 0$ and $\text{target rotation} = 360 - 90 = 270$, the current rotation decrements gradually by 5 until -90 and is then converted to $360 - 90 = 270$:

Frame 1 = $\text{current rotation} = -5$
Frame 4 = $\text{current rotation} = -20$
Frame (last) = $\text{current rotation} = \text{target rotation} = 360 - 90 = 270$

Here is the lock formula to fix the degrees into $[0, 360)$:
$$
lock(a) = \text{if $a \ge 0$, then $a$; otherwise $360 - (-a \mod 360)$}
$$
For defining the $\text{current rotation}$ of that rectangle object in a frame given $a = \text{previous rotation}$ and $b = \text{target rotation}$:
$$
ab = a - b + (\text{if $a - b \gt b - a$, then 0; otherwise 360})
$$
$$
ba = b - a + (\text{if $b - a \gt a - b$, then 0; otherwise 360})
$$
Where $\text{turn speed} = 5$
If $ab < ba$ then
$$
x = lock(a - \text{turn speed})
$$
$$
\text{current rotation} = \text{if $x \lt b$, then $b$; otherwise $x$}
$$
otherwise
$$
x = lock(a + \text{turn speed})
$$
$$
\text{current rotation} = \text{if $x \gt b$, then $b$; otherwise $x$}
$$
The problem is that I get abrupt rotation changes in my simulation:
Demostration GIF
The issue I am seeing is that when you go for example from 180 (current rotation) to 0 (target rotation), it goes to 0 abruptly in 1 frame; the same for 270 (-90) to 0, -45 to 0; except for any angle less than 180, it goes correctly to 0.

Welcome to MSE! <> I don't understand what your code is attempting, but it does seem that you might be over-complicating things. <> Is there a reason to lock degrees to $[0, 360)$ instead of treating angle as an int or float? If there is, can you not just reduce mod $360$?

@AndrewD.Hwang It happens that my 4+(2+2) target rotations are a defined set of rotations (NORTH, NORTHWEST, NORTHEAST, SOUTH, SOUTHWEST, SOUTHEAST, WEST, SOUTH) which have specific angles that go from 0 to 360.

OK, I figured it out. The angle snapping is incorrect. Where $b$ is the target rotation and $x$ is the new rotation from the former frame:
$$
\text{current rotation} = \text{if $x \gt b - (\text{turn speed})$ and $x \lt b + (\text{turn speed})$ then $b$; otherwise $x$}
$$

Full solution:
$$
lock(a) = \text{if $a \ge 0$, then $a$; otherwise $360 - (-a \mod 360)$}
$$
$$
ab = a - b + (\text{if $a - b \gt b - a$, then 0; otherwise 360})
$$
$$
ba = b - a + (\text{if $b - a \gt a - b$, then 0; otherwise 360})
$$
$$
\text{turn speed} = \text{(your number)}
$$
$$
x = lock(a + \text{(if $ab < ba$ then $-\text{turn speed}$; otherwise $+\text{turn speed}$)})
$$
$$
\text{current rotation} = \text{if $x \gt b - (\text{turn speed})$ and $x \lt b + (\text{turn speed})$ then $b$; otherwise $x$}
$$
